# Whenever I put apt update && apt upgrade -y and this will happen

Tags: command-line

```
dpkg: error processing archive /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/cache/apt/archives/procps_3.3.15-6_i686.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/proc/version.h.dpkg-new' (while processing './data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/proc/version.h'): File exists
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/cache/apt/archives/procps_3.3.15-6_i686.deb
E: Sub-process /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You haven't told us what release, nor if you've tried what it suggests in the messages also  (ie. `sudo apt -f install` etc)

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly says that the process is trying to create the file `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/proc/version.h.dpkg-new` but it exists already.

`.dpkg-new` files are generally created by `dpkg` (which is run by `apt`) to unpack the updated files near the old files. When everything has been successfully unpacked, they are renamed over the old files.
<sub>Quoted and adapted from https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/07/18/deciphering-one-of-dpkg-weirdest-errors-unable-to-open-pathtofoo-dpkg-new/.</sub>

However, in your case, another version of that file exists – most likely it’s been kept from a previous `dpkg` run. This can happen due to an interrupted `dpkg` run or the file is kept to manually solve conflicts.

If you don’t need the file anymore, delete (or rename) it and run `dpkg` (or `apt` in your case) again.